# Use HubSpot Form Data on redirectURL

Tags: javascript, jquery, hubspot

I'm looking for a way to send a HubSpot form's data to the url it redirects to after submission so I can use it to auto-fill fields in a custom form on that page. I tried storing the data I need in a cookie, but haven't had any luck. I also found a script on github for appending the data to the redirectURL and set it up in my landing page template code but haven't been able to get it to work:

https://gist.github.com/axiak/2bf8f43d9d4a5f9c883f

```
 /**
 * Append the form data from a HubSpot form automatically
 * to the redirect URL query parameters. These values can
 * then be used on the form to modify the user experience
 * of the Thank You page
 * 
 * LICENSE
 * Form redirect
 * Written in 2015 by Mike Axiak <maxiak@hubspot.com>
 * To the extent possible under law, the author(s) have dedicated all copyright and related and neighboring rights to this software to the public domain worldwide. This software is distributed without any warranty.
 * You should have received a copy of the CC0 Public Domain Dedication along with this software. If not, see <http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/>.
 */
(function() {
  var $ = jQuery;

  var appendFields = function (url, values) {
    var data = {};
    $.each(values, function (i, item) {
      if (item.name !== "hs_context") {
        data[item.name] = item.value;
      }
    });
    if (url.match(/\?/)) {
      return url + "&" + $.param(data);
    } else {
      return url + "?" + $.param(data);
    }
  };

  $(function () {

  $("body").on("submit", "form.hs-form", function (e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    var apiUrl = $form.attr("action");
    var $hsContext = $("input[name='hs_context']", $form);
    var hsContext = JSON.parse($hsContext.val());
    hsContext.redirectUrl = appendFields(hsContext.redirectUrl, $form.serializeArray());
    $hsContext.val(JSON.stringify(hsContext));
  });

  });
})();
```

Comment: I've been scouring the internet for the exact same thing!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could grab all the data associated with the contact using the Hubspot's developer API. Hubspot stores the user token as a cookie name "hubspotutk" and once you've grabbed that you could use

```
GET /contacts/v1/contact/utk/:contact_utk/profile
```

to get all the properties associated with the current contact, which should include everything they filled out in the first page.

[More info on the api call.](http://GET%20/contacts/v1/contact/utk/:contact_utk/profile)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is still relevant.

You need to define "redirectUrl" when you call for form to be created.

```
hbspt.forms.create({
    redirectUrl:"www.google.com",//here you go
    formId: '<your form id>',...}
```

then the code you found from Github will work.

If you define the redirect URL somewhere in the Hubspot management dashboard controller, unfortunately I haven't find a way to see retrieve it using those codes in Github.